# Android AWS Cognito UserPool globalSignout not working when user is signed in from multiple devices

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

In my application I want to invalidate all previous userpool sessions of a particular user when user is signing in again from a different device. But the problem is after calling global signout the session on previous device is still valid. Even after changing the password, the session on previous devices are still there.

```
userPool.getUser("xyzzz").getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
```

After calling above code on previous device, it directly returning the user session with new tokens instead of calling **getAuthenticationDetails** for password.

Is there any way to have only one session at a time for a cognito user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling global signout, Cognito invalidates all access and refresh tokens associated with that particular user. It does not invalidate the id token so that can still be used.

If you try to getSessionInBackground on Android, it checks if the tokens are valid (if the expiration date is valid) in order to return them. However, when you try to use access and refresh tokens, they will not work. When using id tokens, they will expire after one hour. If you can give exact steps for reproducing this, we can investigate further.

Comment: That is what is happening here in my app, we are using Id token to authorize the API calls (API Gateway). My concern is that is there way to invalidate the Id token or decrease its expiry time to 5-10 minutes only. After changing the password on other device it still returning the session without checking for auth details. So let me know if is there any way to invalidate the id token and invalidate the user sessions on other devices.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned, the validity of the id token is 1 hour and global sign out won't invalidate it. The validity cannot be configured either. All other tokens are invalidated. Thanks for bringing this up, I will mention it within the team as a feature request so that it can be prioritized accordingly.

Comment: Actually your first question doesn't specify that you are using the tokens with API Gateway. When accessing external services (not User Pools) such as STS, CIB , API Gateway, access and ID Token will still work if it's not expired even if the user is deleted, disabled, globally signed out.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but please bring this issue up because it is a serious security issue while using cognito with other services.

Comment: @IonutTrestian is this feature added in aws mobile SDK cause I am facing the same issue.